# Swift: Embedded TableViewController doesn't refresh on unwind segue

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a view where I add data to my Firebase database that has an unwind segue to another view controller that I'll call 'parent'. When I press send it unwinds to 'parent' that has an embedded container view (which is a UITableViewController), 'embedded'.'

When I press 'send' and the unwind occurs, 'embedded' does not reflect the data that I just updated (hasn't refreshed). I've tried putting calls to `tableview.reloadData()` all over the place inside 'embedded' (inside viewWillAppear, viewDidLoad, etc). I've also tried accessing it from 'parent' with

```
(self.childViewControllers[0] as! UITableViewController).tableView.reloadData()
```

and also tried adding this line with it

```
(self.childViewControllers[0] as! UITableViewController).viewWillAppear(true)
```

I'm positive index 0 contains the embedded view controller too. I've put this call everywhere from viewWillAppear to prepareForSegue (for the embed segue) and still no luck. Am I missing some important step?

Thanks.

Comment: it should be working if you put the reload in `viewWillAppear`, since it always get called if you back to that screen or showing that screen, put breakpoint in there and check, its more likely you havent put class in storyboard, check again

Comment: I put a break in both parent's viewWillAppear and 'embedded's viewWillAppear and still no luck.

Comment: see if you have put class name in your storyboard

Comment: Yes, I have named the class. What seems impossible to me is that when I put 2 breakpoints into 'embedded', it breaks as I call reloadData in viewWillAppear before the segue, and then when I continue to the next breakpoint which is in cellForRowAt, the tableView already appears with the outdated data. How is this possible to have already loaded while I'm still in a breakpoint inside cellforRowAt?

Comment: does it call code in your unwind method in the one that you unwind to?

Comment: I fixed it... ended up the problem was something unrelated, the array that I stored my data in never resetted every time I unwind to the view, so it was still using the old data every time. All I had to do was to call removeAll on that array in 'embedded' in viewWillAppear and it was fixed. THanks for the help!